# C# WinForms - Show headers, index, and values in ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have `List<int> myNumbersList`. I want to show that list in a ListBox `lbNumbers`.

I know I can do `lbNumbers.DataSource = myNumbersList`, but I also want to show the index for each value, and before the values start, I want to show headers. Like such:

```
Index  Value
0      100
1      47
2      79
...
```

Comment: For these and many many other powerful options ListView was introduced. When in doubt always use it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it will be easier for you to achieve your goals if you use a [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview?view=netframework-4.7.2) and set its [View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.view?view=netframework-4.7.2) property to `Details`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own item that has both Index and value together. this is using Linq:

```
lbNumbers.DataSource = myNumbersList.Select((x,i) => $"{i} - {x}).ToArray();
```

Considering your commnet (just insert "Index - Value" at the index 0):

```
 lbNumbers.DataSource = myNumbersList.Select((x,i) => $"{i} - {x}).ToList()
        .Insert(0, "Index - Value");
```

Comment: And if I want to have headers "Index" and "Value" for the first line of the ListBox?

Comment: I was able to add the header lines by doing `var myList = new List<string> { string.Format($"{"Index",-10}{"Value",-10}") };` `myList.AddRange(myNumbersList.Select((x, n) => string.Format($"{n,-13}{x,-10}")));` `lbNumbers.DataSource = myList;`

Comment: @JED the way I suggested is not the only way of doing it, for example you may add each item one by one: `listbox1.Items.Add("Index - Value"); for(int i=0;i<myNumbersList.Length;i++) listbox1.Items.Add($"{i} - {myNumbersList[i]}");`

Comment: No offense meant but this is a terrible idea. It is what op asked for but still terrible, even with a fixed size font. ListView is the correct way, not making a listbox do what it was not meant to do. In addition to an ugly font one would probably also have to deal with the user selecting the 'header' etc..

Comment: Thanks for answering the question I asked, but I will go with "Use ListView" as the correct answer